# Pulling up existing form mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, mddialog, angularjs-material

I'm new to AngularJS Material and have created link that opens up a dialog box that houses a form. Right now, when someone clicks on the link, it opens up a new form, however if that person already has a record, I want the link to pull up the existing form so that they can make edits.  What do I have to change so that this happens?

My HTML:

```
<md-icon class="material-icons md-72" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)" role="button">assignment</md-icon>
```

My Client Script:

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'material-modal',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
            preserveScope: true,
            scope:$scope
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to your modal and use them into the modal.

In example, if the concerned person is registered in your *scope* as `user`, you can pass him to the modal using **`locals`**

```
$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'material-modal',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true,
      preserveScope: true,
      scope:$scope,
      locals: { person: $scope.user }
    })
    .then(function(answer) {
  };
```

Then, in your `DialogController` you will be able to retrieve your param.

```
  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, person) {
    // Affect to the current scope your param
    $scope.person = person;
    // Actions with this person
  }
```